# How should I move my long functions out of MainWindow (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, refactoring

I'm writing a G-Code post-processor in QT. The app basically has the user select a file to work with, pick some parameters, and then parses the file and manipulates it a bit.

Right now, I have all the manipulation as a function called when the user decides to save the newly edited file.

```
void MainWindow::on_writeGcodeButton_clicked()
{
    writeGcode();
}

void MainWindow::writeGcode(){
    <Get a bunch of info from  the ui>
    <Search through a file and manipulate it>
    <Output result>
}
```

This seems clunky to me, as I have this huge piece of logic that has nothing to do with the MainWindow (besides getting a bunch of variables from the ui) inside the MainWindow code. It's also getting really hard to navigate around the file, since there's methods for all the button presses mixed in with this long G-Code manipulation method.

I'm new to C++ and Qt, and I'm still getting the hang of header and source files. What's the best way for me to refactor my code? Should I:

1. Create a new class, and fill it with static methods that take in as parameters all of the info collected from the main ui?

   ```
   //gcodeParser.cpp
   public static void writeGcode(String a, String b, String c ....) {
       //Search through file, manipulate, output result
   }
   ```
2. Create a new parser class, and instantiate it. (This doesn't seem  like a good idea to me...)
3. Leave it as it is, there's no problem
4. Something else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good idea is to create a structure and name it "Parameters" which will contain a variable for each parameter that ca be set from the ui. You will create an instance of Parameter inside your mainwindow class and set its values whenever "OK" is clicked or whenever the user, for example, presses a button. A good piece of advice is to set some default parameters to your structure.
After this create a class and name it "Parser" that has as parameters to its constructor, the full file path of your file and the reference of you "Parameters" object. Inside this class create methods that have to do with search or manipulation.
Finally, (assuming that your output is shown on your mainwindow.ui) you can emit signals that will be listened for slots of mainwindow passing the information of your output in order to be displayed on mainwindow's controls.
In the end you must only have inside mainwindow.cpp:

1. the creation of "Parameters" and "Parser" objects.
2. the slots (and connects) that listen to the user's actions.
3. the slots (and connects) that listen to the signal that are emitted from "Parser"in order to display the output on your mainwindow.ui.

Actually there are many ways that you can choose to refactor your code (You can have a look on MVC pattern). And to find the best one demands experience, study on the design patterns and most of all consideration about the needs of your application, the needs of making it easily expandable in the future and the ability to have closed blocks of code that will not be affected wen an addition will be done in the future. This was just my approach. Good luck and I will be happy to help again, if you need it.

Comment: @Memnarch1113 : if this answer answers your question, please mark it as correct, in order to close the question.